# How exactly works Python decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I am absolutly new in Python (I came from Java and C#)

I am stufying the **decorator** topic. So I have the following example:

```
# DECORATOR:
def my_decorator(func):
  def wrap_func():
    print('**************')
    func()
    print('**************')
  return wrap_func


@my_decorator
def hello():
  print('Hello World')

hello()
```

It seems to me that this is the logic (but I am not sure of this:

I am defining a **my_decorator** function taking another function as parameter. This **my_decorator** function wrap the function passed as parameter into a **wrap_func()** function that execute the function passed as parameter. In addition this **wrap_func()** function can perform some extra logic before and after the execution of the function passed as parameter (it is decorating the original function.

To say to the interpreter that a specific function have to use the decorator I have to use the syntax **@decorator_name** before the function definition.

So in my case: when I perform **hello()** call: Python know that the **hello()** function have to be decorated by **my_decorator** decorator so it is not directly executing the **hello()** function but it is performing the **my_decorator()** function passing  **hello()** reference as parameter. So it can add extra logic before and after the **hello()** invoaction.

Is this reasoning correct or am I missing something??

I have another doubt: why the decorator function return the function that wrap our decoration logic?

Comment: Have you read anything on the subject before posting? I guess not…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A decorator is just syntactic sugar for a function call.

The decoration

```
@my_decorator
def hello():
    print('Hello world')
```

is equivalent to

```
def hello():
    print('Hello world')

hello = my_decorator(hello)
```

So in this case, using the decorator syntax is the same as defining the following function directly:

```
def hello():
    print('**************')
    print('Hello world')
    print('**************')
```

The decorator creates a function that calls `print('**************')`, then calls the *original* function, then calls `print('**************')` again.

If you had only planned on decorating once function, this is obviously just a lot of unnecessary boiler plate. But if you were decorating *multiple* functions, the abstraction pays off:

```
# DECORATOR:
def my_decorator(func):
  def wrap_func():
    print('**************')
    func()
    print('**************')
  return wrap_func


@my_decorator
def hello():
  print('Hello World')

@my_decorator
def how_are_you():
  print("How are you doing?")

@my_decorator
def goodbye():
  print('Goodbye, world')
```

vs

```
def hello():
    print('**************')
    print('Hello world')
    print('**************')

def how_are_your():
    print('**************')
    print('How are you doing')
    print('**************')

def good_bye():
    print('**************')
    print('Goodbye world')
    print('**************')
```

especially if you later decide to wrap each output with `==============` instead of `**************`.

Answer (score 1):

Decorators are just a syntactic sugar. This:

```
@decorator
def func():
    pass
```

is equivalent to this:

```
def func():
    pass

func = decorator(func)
```